# Android Textview's setText() causes native memory to grow all the time

Tags: android, textview, out-of-memory

In one of my own applications, the program needs to run for a long time. I find that after running for a few days or half a month, the memory rises very high.

The program uses a lot of things, like, cameras, a lot of low-level algorithm libraries written in C, C++, and so on. So, it needs a lot of memory. After a long period of exclusion, it was initially determined that it was caused by `TextView.setText()`.

To verify this problem, I created a new clean project with the following test code (layout a `Textview` control):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean isActing = false;
  //public int i=0;
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.counter);

       //handler.sendEmptyMessage(200);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                isActing = true;
                while (isActing) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
                            
                           //textView.setText(String.valueOf(((i++)%2)));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        isActing = false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

While the app runs, the memory of the native keeps constantly growing. So, the memory will become very high after half a month of operation, and I don't know the cause of the problem. So, I don't know how to deal with it.